# Building a list using Backbone Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to build a  list using a BackBone collection.. For some reason, i am not able to get them printed on the page..

js file

```
var DataCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model : dataModel
        });

        var dataModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults : {
                dataID : 'unknown',
                text : 'unknown',

            }
        });

        var link1 = new dataModel({ dataID: "1", text: "OMC" });
        var link2 = new dataModel({ dataID: "2", text: "Marvin Gaye" });
        var link3 = new dataModel({ dataID: "3", text: "OMC" });

        var myDataCollection = new DataCollection([ link1, link2, link3]);


   var threatData = {

                myDataCollection: myDataCollection
        };

    var compiledTemplate = Handlebars
                .compile(myTemplate);
        $('#myTable').html(
                compiledTemplate (threatData));
```

html file

```
<ul id="Linklist">
             {{#each myDataCollection}}
                <li><a data-id="{{dataID}}" href="#">{{text}}</a></li>
             {{/each}}
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the template rendering to work, you need to first convert the Backbone collection to JSON.

```
var threatData = {
            myDataCollection: myDataCollection.toJSON()
    };
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LdMb2/)

Comment: @Skyrim1 no worries, I've been there for sure!